# Can I proliferate counters on a Skullbriar in the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So if [Skullbriar, the Walking Grave](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Skullbriar%2C%20the%20Walking%20Grave) dies with a +1/+1 counter on it; in the graveyard he'd still have it.

So my question is:
Can I proliferate the counters on him while he's still in the graveyard?

Answer (score 11):

No. Proliferate is defined as ([CR 701.27a](https://media.wizards.com/2022/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020220908.pdf)):

> To proliferate means to choose any number of permanents and/or players that have a counter, then give each one additional counter of each kind that permanent or player already has.

A card in a graveyard is not a permanent (or a player!) so it cannot be chosen. From CR 110.1:

> A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield.

Answer (score 4):

**No**

Proliferate is defined in [rule 701.27a](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Proliferate):

> To proliferate means to choose any number of permanents and/or players that have a counter, then give each one additional counter of each kind that permanent or player already has.

Permanents are objects on the battlefield, so you cannot proliferate counters on objects in other zones, including the graveyard.